# Parse a value from a message in Teams using Flow

Tags: webhooks, microsoft-teams, connector, power-automate

Currently I send MessageCards to Teams via the O365 connecter from Cherwell.  In the message there is an @NAME being the name of the technician in Cherwell.
Does anyone know of a way to parse a new message in FLOW (starting with the 'When a new channel message is added' method) to use the name after the @ as a mention in the channel.
So basically the Message appears via the O365 connector, then the flow runs to mention the person in the channel where the message arrived?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked a treat.  I parsed out the email address from the JSON that was sent as the MessageCard then created a flow that created a variable and wrapped the  around it and using he Flow Bot now have the mentions sending around from a MessageCard being sent via the O365 connector to Teams.